# Problema con actualización en Merge Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando en una inserción de datos validando el campo `NIT` que existe en ambas tablas, lo que necesito es que cuando el campo `NIT` se encuentre ya registrado actualice los campos `TELEFONO2` y `CORREO2`.

Cuando no se encuentre el mismo `NIT` debe insertar todos todos los datos de la tabla origen a la tabla destino, el query es el siguiente:

```
MERGE INTO CPROMO_UNIFICADO d
    USING CLIENTES_PROMO 
    ON (d.NIT = o.NIT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET d."CORREO2" = o."CORREO1",
              d."TELEFONO2" = o."TELEFONO1"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ("NIT","DPI","ULTIMO_CONSUMO","NOMBRE_COMPLETO","PRIMER_NOMBRE","SEGUNDO_NOMBRE",
   "PRIMER_APELLIDO","SEGUNDO_APELLIDO","TELEFONO1","TELEFONO2","CORREO1","CORREO2")
   VALUES (o."NIT",o."DPI",o."ULTIMO_CONSUMO",o."NOMBRE_COMPLETO",o."PRIMER_NOMBRE",o."SEGUNDO_NOMBRE",
   o."PRIMER_APELLIDO",o."SEGUNDO_APELLIDO",o."TELEFONO1",o."TELEFONO2",o."CORREO1",o."CORREO2");
```

El inconveniente que tengo es que cuando no me funciona la sección de `WHEN MATCHED` debido a que siempre esta insertando los datos, en ningún momento actualiza.